# Using the "place_with_parent_names" column to create a "state" column for df1. state name always appears after "|Brasil|" but my output encloses [ ]

Tags: python, pandas

Find attached below the image of the input and output of the code as an image
[code output and input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bevt.png)

Comment: Please make the title appropriate to the logic you are struggling with rather than the task(involving names from that data).

Comment: You are using str.split which creates a list. Since you need the second element of that list, use df1['State'].str[1] at the end

Comment: @Asettisriharsha I am actually new here

Comment: It would greatly help if you can add a minimal reproducible example with sample input & expected output.

Answer (score 0):

## column to create state

> as per my indrstanding

> I am writing this code

```
# Split place_with_parent_names column by "|"
split_names = df1["place_with_parent_names"].str.split("|")

# Find index of "Brasil" in each list and add 1 to get index of state name
state_index = split_names.apply(lambda x: x.index("Brasil") + 1)

# Extract state name using state_index
df1["state"] = split_names.apply(lambda x: x[state_index.iloc[0]])
```

please do upvote and support i guess it works

Answer (score 0):

I actually thought that to carryout that task I will solve it with the lines of code below:

```
df1["state"] = df1["place_with_parent_names"].str.split("|", expand =True)
df1.head()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).